# TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable in Python... was working yesterday

Tags: python, typeerror

```
    # Remove non-hashtags from hashtag list. 
hashtag_metadata['hashtags'] = hashtag_metadata['hashtags'].apply(
    lambda hashtag_list: [h for h in hashtag_list if h.startswith('#')])

    # Create a flattened list of all hashtags
all_hashtags = [hashtag for hashtags in hashtag_metadata['hashtags'] for hashtag in hashtags]

    # Coerce to a set to remove duplicate entries
# Sort to ensure reproducibility of results
all_hashtags = sorted(list(set(all_hashtags)))

    # Build lookup for finding hashtag number based on hashtag name
hashtag_lookup = {hashtag: i for i, hashtag in enumerate(all_hashtags)}
```

---

```
----> 3     lambda hashtag_list: [h for h in hashtag_list if h.startswith('#')])
      4 
      5 # Create a flattened list of all hashtags

TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

The full notebook is here https://github.com/AlecMorgan/Automatic-Image-Tagger/blob/master/modeling.ipynb

Comment: I am not able to open the notebook. Can you post a small sample dataset? The error implies that `hashtag_list` is a float object and hence not iterable.

Comment: We recommend that you include all required code / data in questions themselves because this will prevent deadlinks and make your question/answer more searchable.

Comment: Do you remember what changed since yesterday? The error suggests that hashtag_list is not in fact a list but a float. Only a list or collection is iterable.